# IOS conversion of UTC to local time not accurate

Tags: ios, swift, utc

I'm trying to convert a UTC to device local time in Swift 4. I found many solutions on `stackoverflow` for that and I implemented them in my code. My code works fine but it doesn't return the right answer.

My code is:

```
func UTCToLocal() -> String {
    let a = "2:36:27 PM"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss aa"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: a)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.defaultDate = Date()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss aa"

    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
}
```

According to my local time, Lebanon, this method should return the value 5:36:27 PM. However, it is returning 4:36:27 PM.

Note: I checked my device's local time and it's set correctly

Comment: Are you on summer time?

Comment: `isDaylightSavingTime` of DateFormatter() is your friend here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateFormatter returns unexpected date for Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49689671/dateformatter-returns-unexpected-date-for-timezone).

Comment: @MartinR i don't think it is a duplicate. Carpsen90's solution solved the problem and it is different than the question you posted.

Comment: @SinanNoureddine: It is exactly the same problem, and setting `dateFormatter.defaultDate` properly does solve it. Carpsen90 suggested a different solution (and I still have some doubts about that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to [Daylight Saving Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/lebanon) in Lebanon. You can take the time offset into consideration by using the [`daylightSavingTimeOffset(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2293268-daylightsavingtimeoffset) method on your time zone:

```
func UTCToLocal() -> String {
    let a = "2:36:27 PM"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss aa"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: a)

    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    let offset = dateFormatter.timeZone.daylightSavingTimeOffset(for: dt!)
    dateFormatter.defaultDate = Date()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss aa"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt! + offset)
}

UTCToLocal()
```

Note that `dt` is "Jan 1, 2000 at 2:36 PM" since you haven't specified the `.day`, `.month`, and `.year` date components in `a`

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this can give a wrong result on days where the clock is adjusted (from/to DST). `daylightSavingTimeOffset()` gives the daylight offset of “now”, not of the to-be-converted time.